# hacer para que jsPDF cree una pagina automatica con el contenido restante

Tags: angular, pdf, jspdf

tengo el siguiente problema , intento hacer que jsPDF con angular , me genere varias paginas en pdf , he logrado que me cree una segunda pero esta aparece en blanco y no con el contenido que falta del html.

```
import { Component, ElementRef, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import jsPDF from 'jspdf';
import html2canvas from 'html2canvas';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor() {

  }


  public downloadPDF() {
    // Extraemos el
    const DATA:any  = document.getElementById('elhtml');
    const doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');

    const options = {
      background: 'white',

      scale: 3
    };
    html2canvas(DATA , options).then((canvas) => {

      const img = canvas.toDataURL('image/PNG');

      // Add image Canvas to PDF
      const bufferX = 15;
      const bufferY = 15;
      const imgProps = (doc as any).getImageProperties(img);
      const pdfWidth = doc.internal.pageSize.getWidth() - 2 * bufferX;
      const pdfHeight = (imgProps.height * pdfWidth) / imgProps.width;
      doc.addImage(img, 'PNG', bufferX, bufferY, pdfWidth, pdfHeight, undefined, 'FAST');
   if ( pdfHeight >= bufferX + bufferY){
    doc.addPage();

   }

      return doc;
   


    }).then((docResult) => {
      docResult.save(`${new Date().toISOString()}Descarga.pdf`);
    });
}
}
```

el contenido que pasa a pdf es por un id , en mi caso es  `<div id="elhtml">`  que esta en el html que encierra todo el contenido.
me logra crear una segunda hoja pero en blanco , como deberia hacer para poder generarr mas de una hoja si fuese neceario segun el html ?

Parte del html es lo siguiente , solo es una parte ya que son 80 formularios (en este caso les quite los form, solo para que primero guarde en mas de una hoja y despues preocurme de la logica js que la tengo lista)

```
<div id="elhtml">
   <h2>1° Procesamiento AUDITIVO</h2>
  <br>
            <br>
  <b>1-</b>    Reacciona fuertemente a sonidos inesperados o altos (por ejemplo, sirenas, perros ladrando, secadora de pelo).
  <br>

  <input id="rdo_5" type="radio" value="5" name="price1" onchange="getPriceUpdate();getAzul();getVerde();getAmarillo();getRojo()">   CS
  <input id="rdo_4" type="radio" value="4" name="price1" onchange="getPriceUpdate();getAzul();getVerde();getAmarillo();getRojo()">   F

  <input id="rdo_3" type="radio" value="3" name="price1" onchange="getPriceUpdate();getAzul();getVerde();getAmarillo();getRojo()">  MT

  <input id="rdo_2" type="radio" value="2" name="price1" onchange="getPriceUpdate();getAzul();getVerde();getAmarillo();getRojo()">   O

  <input id="rdo_1" type="radio" value="1" name="price1" onchange="getPriceUpdate();getAzul();getVerde();getAmarillo();getRojo()">   CN
  <br>
  <br>
  <b>2-</b>  Se cubre los oídos con las manos para protegerlos de los sonidos.
  <br>

  <input id="rdo_5" type="radio" value="5" name="price2" onchange="getPriceUpdate();getAzul();getVerde();getAmarillo();getRojo()">   CS
  <input id="rdo_4" type="radio" value="4" name="price2" onchange="getPriceUpdate();getAzul();getVerde();getAmarillo();getRojo()">   F

  <input id="rdo_3" type="radio" value="3" name="price2" onchange="getPriceUpdate();getAzul();getVerde();getAmarillo();getRojo()">  MT

  <input id="rdo_2" type="radio" value="2" name="price2" onchange="getPriceUpdate();getAzul();getVerde();getAmarillo();getRojo()">   O

  <input id="rdo_1" type="radio" value="1" name="price2" onchange="getPriceUpdate();getAzul();getVerde();getAmarillo();getRojo()">   CN
  <br>
  <br>
  <b>3-</b>  Le cuesta trabajo completar las tareas cuando hay música o la televisión está prendida.
  <br>

  <input id="rdo_5" type="radio" value="5" name="price3" onchange="getPriceUpdate();getAzul();getVerde();getAmarillo();getRojo()">   CS
  <input id="rdo_4" type="radio" value="4" name="price3" onchange="getPriceUpdate();getAzul();getVerde();getAmarillo();getRojo()">   F

  <input id="rdo_3" type="radio" value="3" name="price3" onchange="getPriceUpdate();getAzul();getVerde();getAmarillo();getRojo()">  MT

  <input id="rdo_2" type="radio" value="2" name="price3" onchange="getPriceUpdate();getAzul();getVerde();getAmarillo();getRojo()">   O

  <input id="rdo_1" type="radio" value="1" name="price3" onchange="getPriceUpdate();getAzul();getVerde();getAmarillo();getRojo()">   CN
  <br>
  <br>
  <b>4-</b>  Se distrae cuando hay mucho ruido alrededor.
  <br>

  <input id="rdo_5" type="radio" value="5" name="price4" onchange="getPriceUpdate();getAzul();getVerde();getAmarillo();getRojo()">   CS
  <input id="rdo_4" type="radio" value="4" name="price4" onchange="getPriceUpdate();getAzul();getVerde();getAmarillo();getRojo()">   F

  <input id="rdo_3" type="radio" value="3" name="price4" onchange="getPriceUpdate();getAzul();getVerde();getAmarillo();getRojo()">  MT

  <input id="rdo_2" type="radio" value="2" name="price4" onchange="getPriceUpdate();getAzul();getVerde();getAmarillo();getRojo()">   O

  <input id="rdo_1" type="radio" value="1" name="price4" onchange="getPriceUpdate();getAzul();getVerde();getAmarillo();getRojo()">   CN
            <br>
  <br>
  <b>5-</b> Se vuelve improductivo (a) con el ruido de fondo (por ejemplo, ventilador, refrigerador).
  <br>

  <input id="rdo_5" type="radio" value="5" name="price5" onchange="getPriceUpdate();getAzul();getVerde();getAmarillo();getRojo()">   CS
  <input id="rdo_4" type="radio" value="4" name="price5" onchange="getPriceUpdate();getAzul();getVerde();getAmarillo();getRojo()">   F

  <input id="rdo_3" type="radio" value="3" name="price5" onchange="getPriceUpdate();getAzul();getVerde();getAmarillo();getRojo()">  MT

  <input id="rdo_2" type="radio" value="2" name="price5" onchange="getPriceUpdate();getAzul();getVerde();getAmarillo();getRojo()">   O

  <input id="rdo_1" type="radio" value="1" name="price5" onchange="getPriceUpdate();getAzul();getVerde();getAmarillo();getRojo()">   CN
            <br>
  <br>
  <b>6-</b>  Parece ignorarme o no escuchar lo que estoy diciendo.

  <br>

  <input id="rdo_5" type="radio" value="5" name="price6" onchange="getPriceUpdate();getAzul();getVerde();getAmarillo();getRojo()">   CS
  <input id="rdo_4" type="radio" value="4" name="price6" onchange="getPriceUpdate();getAzul();getVerde();getAmarillo();getRojo()">   F

  <input id="rdo_3" type="radio" value="3" name="price6" onchange="getPriceUpdate();getAzul();getVerde();getAmarillo();getRojo()">  MT

  <input id="rdo_2" type="radio" value="2" name="price6" onchange="getPriceUpdate();getAzul();getVerde();getAmarillo();getRojo()">   O

  <input id="rdo_1" type="radio" value="1" name="price6" onchange="getPriceUpdate();getAzul();getVerde();getAmarillo();getRojo()">   CN
  <br>
            <br>




</div> 
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="downloadPDF()">Descargar</button>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: Hola, puedes replicar el problema en Stackblitz?

Comment: nunca lo e ocupado y me da un problema con el componente , de igual manera copie todo el ts

Comment: no puedo acceder al código, por favor chequea y corrige los posibles errores que se presenten

Comment: Stackblitz me dice que tengo un error de componente , pero en el post esta todo el ts

Comment: agrega el contenido del html que esperas renderizar

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que iterar el html2canvas para generar todas las paginas que quieras crear , según con los datos con los que se vaya generando , y luego con el JSpdf iterar sobre todos los Canvas que hayas generado , dejo un ejemplo.

Aquí generas y coges todos los datos con htmlElement luego iterar sobre ellos , te creas un variable con los datos de JsPDF e iterar con esa variable sobre los canvas , me explico como un libro cerrado , pero es lo que a mi me ha servido.:

```
  async generarPDF2(event: MouseEvent): Promise<void> {
    console.log('Inicio de generarPDF');
    event.preventDefault();
    this.cargandoPDF = true; // Activa el loader
    const hojas = document.querySelectorAll('.hoja');
    const pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'a4');

    for (let i = 0; i < hojas.length; i++) {
      await html2canvas(hojas[i] as HTMLElement, {
        useCORS: true,
        backgroundColor: null,
        scale: 1,
      }).then((canvas) => {
        const imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 0.75);
        const imgWidth = 210; // Ancho de página A4 en mm
        const imgHeight = (canvas.height * imgWidth) / canvas.width;

        if (i > 0) {
          pdf.addPage();
        }
        pdf.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, 0, imgWidth, imgHeight);
      });
    }
```